# Use `EditorSceneManager.SaveScene` at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have scenes where the player instantiates lots of prefabs and I need them to persist. Can I use [`EditorSceneManager.SaveScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SaveScene.html) to do this? Or is this completely wrong?

If not, is there something similar? I need a way to save instantiated prefabs in its scene.

Comment: How about saving just the bits you need? An asset exists for that https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-save-load-72578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use EditorSceneManager.SaveScene to do this?

**No**

> If not, is there something similar?

**No**

There is no built-in function to save instantiated objects during gameplay. You have to implement this yourself as *the code to do this will be big and a little bit complicated.*

You need to write an `Editor` extension plugin for this. When Object is instantiated, save that GameObject into a `List` with it's information such as the type of the object, position, rotation, color and components that are attached to that GameObject.

When stop is pressed, use the `Editor` mode and that `List` to re-instantiate those GameObjects back by looping over the `List`.

Detect Scene Play and Stop:

```
void Start()
{
    EditorApplication.playmodeStateChanged = OnPlayModeEnter;
}


void OnPlayModeEnter()
{
    if (EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode)
    {
        Debug.Log("Playing!");
    }else{
         Debug.Log("Stopped Playing!");
    }
}
```

You do the rest!

Comment: I was afraid I'd get that answer XD thanks! and thanks for the part for detecting scene play/stop

Comment: @MinaMichael Sorry for that. Unity is working on a save future while scene is running. I don't know when the release time will be. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Still not possible in 2018.2.

My work around is to save a prefab using  `PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab()`.

Comment: What is this? Random fraggles edit my post? How is this possible? Fraggle didn't change anything. Whats going on here?